# Getting unexpected behaviour when using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly

I'm working on a webapp using wildfly and hibernate.

Below is some of my code and config files.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">removed</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql:reportbuilderwebservices</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">removed</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  <mapping class="org.declercq.reportbuilderback.models.User"/>
  <mapping class="org.declercq.reportbuilderback.models.Permission"/>
  <mapping class="org.declercq.reportbuilderback.models.Role"/>
  <mapping class="org.declercq.reportbuilderback.models.Vulnerability"/>
  <mapping class="org.declercq.reportbuilderback.models.Finding"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My model class User.java with annotations:

```
package org.declercq.reportbuilderback.models;



import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity 
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String emailAddress;

    public User(String userName, String password, String emailAddress) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }






}
```

My DAO method:

```
public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        System.out.println("0");
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println("0,5");
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<User>allUsers=null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println("1");
            allUsers = session.createQuery("from User u").getResultList();
            System.out.println("2");
            tx.commit();
            System.out.println("3");

        }
        catch(HibernateException e){
            if(tx != null){
                tx.rollback();
                System.out.println("4");
            }
            return allUsers;
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
            System.out.println("5");
            return allUsers;
        }
    }
```

My hibernate.util:

```
package org.declercq.reportbuilderback.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());


        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);

            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

My webservice:

```
package org.declercq.reportbuilderback.webservices;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import org.declercq.reportbuilderback.dao.UserDao;
import org.declercq.reportbuilderback.models.User;

@Path("/userwebservice")
public class UserWebService {

    @Path("/users")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<User> listUsers(){
        System.out.println("HERE");
        List<User>allUsers=new UserDao().getAllUsers();
        System.out.println("Now here");
        System.out.println("Size: "+allUsers.size());
        return allUsers;                
    }

}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>reportbuilderback</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.declercq.reportbuilderback</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1211.jre7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My server output:

The strange thing is, if you look at my output in console (where I use the system.out.println), the DAO code jumps from creating a transaction straight to closing the session, it doesn't even build my query. 
The result is of course that my database query result is null, hence the nullpointerexception. This I understand, but I have no idea why the DAO code isn't executing correctly...
I'm thinking it's because of my pom configuration, something library at compile versus library from wildfly, but I have no idea...

UPDATE 1:

After changing my code as described below:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        System.out.println("0");
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println("0,5");
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<User>allUsers=null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println("1");
            //allUsers = session.createQuery("select u from User u").getResultList();
            allUsers=session.createCriteria(User.class).list();
            System.out.println("2");
            tx.commit();
            System.out.println("3");

        }
        catch(HibernateException e){
            if(tx != null){
                tx.rollback();
                System.out.println("4");
            }
            return allUsers;
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
            System.out.println("5");
            return allUsers;
        }
    }
```

I now get following output:

```
08:32:37,957 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
08:32:38,350 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
08:32:38,467 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
08:32:41,471 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found org.declercq.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called org.declercq.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.dodeploy
08:32:41,641 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
08:32:41,715 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
08:32:41,728 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
08:32:41,856 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
08:32:41,958 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
08:32:41,990 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
08:32:42,007 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
08:32:42,059 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
08:32:42,097 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
08:32:42,123 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
08:32:42,126 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
08:32:42,175 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
08:32:42,208 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
08:32:42,213 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
08:32:42,473 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
08:32:42,477 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
08:32:42,523 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
08:32:42,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
08:32:42,853 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
08:32:42,889 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
08:32:42,897 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
08:32:43,108 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
08:32:43,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
08:32:43,251 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
08:32:43,729 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
08:32:44,048 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
08:32:44,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/wouter/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments
08:32:44,112 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "org.declercq.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "org.declercq.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
08:32:44,508 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
08:32:44,547 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
08:32:44,617 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
08:32:44,614 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
08:32:44,621 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
08:32:44,616 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
08:32:44,623 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
08:32:44,633 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
08:32:44,841 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
08:32:47,678 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment org.declercq.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
08:32:47,783 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
08:32:48,163 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.4)
08:32:48,236 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
08:32:48,315 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = org.declercq.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war_org.postgresql.Driver_9_4
08:32:51,378 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.declercq.reportbuilderback.webservices.ConfigApp
08:32:51,429 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /org.declercq.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
08:32:51,498 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "org.declercq.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "org.declercq.reportbuilderback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
08:32:51,731 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
08:32:51,731 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
08:32:51,732 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 14785ms - Started 476 of 724 services (404 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
08:32:57,477 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) HERE
08:32:57,480 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 0
08:32:57,639 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (default task-3) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.3.Final}
08:32:57,641 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (default task-3) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
08:32:57,644 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (default task-3) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
08:32:58,527 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (default task-3) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
08:32:58,725 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-3) HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
08:32:58,727 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-3) HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql:reportbuilderwebservices]
08:32:58,729 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-3) HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=reportbuilderwebservices, password=****}
08:32:58,730 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-3) HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
08:32:58,734 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (default task-3) HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10 (min=1)
08:32:58,844 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (default task-3) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
08:32:59,106 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (default task-3) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08:32:59,109 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (default task-3) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@48ea9b0e
08:32:59,449 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl] (default task-3) HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@43b645ed'
08:32:59,632 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 0,5
08:32:59,636 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 1
08:32:59,640 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (default task-3) HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
08:32:59,653 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 2
08:32:59,657 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 3
08:32:59,658 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 5
08:32:59,659 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Now here
08:32:59,660 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Size: 0
```

So, 2 issues here: 1) for some reason, this executes while the previous method of createQuery did not. I really want to know why, since this way (using criteria) apparently is deprecated. 2) Most important reason of all: I print out the size of allUsers at the end, the size is 0, which is absolutely not possible, since there are 3 user accounts added in that users table.

Can someone assist please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`createQuery` is returning null, which usually means that there is something wrong with the query string. You could try, for example:

```
allUsers = session.createQuery("from User").getResultList();
```

Or JPA compliant way:

```
allUsers = session.createQuery("select u from User u").getResultList();
```

Or without hql:

```
allUsers = session.createCriteria(User.class).list();
```

Comment: Sorry, just changed it like you said, using "from User", still exactly the same behaviour. Already tried that before too.

Comment: Interesting - what about the JPA complian way: `"select u from User u"`?

Comment: Nope, same issue, again jumps from system.out.println(0) to 0,5 to 1 to 5, completely skipping the query creation and execution.
I also checked the usual suspects, example using the correct imports from javax.persistence instead of org.hibernate, but this is already ok as you can see in my model class. I'm also sure that the users-table exists, when using the progresql console I can manually execute "select * from users", which gives me the content (I added 3 users in it).

Comment: It's not skipping the query creation, it throws an exception when initializing the query, as you can see from the stacktrace. The cause of that is that the `createQuery` command is returning null, which is usually caused by malformed query string.

Comment: I have no idea why it would be doing that. I based my createquery on countless examples I've found elsewhere, both here on stackoverflow, in other online tutorials, ...